# Run batch file from Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi, batch-file, delphi-xe

Does anybody know, is there any way (default or third-party) to start batch file which is opened in Delphi IDE editor, by keypress or button?

I mean simply press, say, F9, and get cmd.exe window with my batch file, from editor, runnning in this window.

In some older Delphi version, might be Delphi 5, batch files could be created as projects, so there it was really F9. However, in Delphi XE I see no such project "type".

Comment: Maybe you can add CMD.EXE to your tools, and then run your batch file using something this: `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE $PROJECTFILENAME`

Comment: @iManBiglari This should be an answer rather than a comment

Comment: @iManBiglari, really, put it as answer, and I'll accept it. It really works. Wonder how didn't I realize it yourself :)

Some additions to your future answer - instead of `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE` I put more general `$(ComSpec)`, and parameters there are specified in different edit field, plus they are a bit different - `/c$EDNAME $SAVE`, where `$EDIT` - expanded file name of topmost editor file, and `$SAVE` tells IDE to save that file before running tool.

In any case, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add `CMD.EXE` (or as you yourself mentioned, `$(ComSpec)`) in the tools menu, with `/c$EDNAME` as the parameter. Also, you can tell the IDE to save your file before running the external tool with `$SAVE` macro